# Line graph of a single Cell that is dynamically changing

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have one cell in Excel that is simply the subtraction result of two other cells. The subtraction number is dynamic i.e. it is continually changing throughout the day based on the values of the two original cells.
I want to plot a line graph that keeps track on the chart of every single number change in the subtraction cell. How do I do that.
Currently I can create a simple line chart but it plots ONLY the number currently showing in the cell. i.e when the number changes, the graph doesnt keep the previous number and so on...

Comment: You'd better provide the sample about the table here.

Comment: You can't plot a chart with data that isn't there. So, you'll need to figure out a way to store the history of the old values by adding to it when the value changes.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the worksheet change event to store the new value when it is calculated.  If I have cells A1:B1 which change, and cell C1 = A1 + B1, and a Table in columns E and F:

[image]

If I use this sub procedure in the code behind Sheet1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'if either the value in A1 or B1 changes, then the value in C1 will be changing
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$B$1" Then

    'if there's currently no data in the table, just put the data in the first row of the table
    If Sheet1.Range("F2") = "" Then
    
        Sheet1.Range("F2") = Sheet1.Range("C1") 'the newly calculated value
        Sheet1.Range("E2") = Now() 'the current date and time
        
    Else 'otherwise, find the bottom of the table, and put the data in the next row
    
        With Sheet1.Range("F100000").End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1, 0) = Sheet1.Range("C1") 'the newly calculated value
            .Offset(1, -1) = Now() 'the current date and time
        End With
        
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

You can see that as either cell A1 or B1 changes, the new value is added to the bottom of the table with a timestamp and the chart, which is created from the Table, updates as new data is added:

[image]